cypress.config.js of setupNodeEvents function does not fire the GET request using the Axios library
I want the after:spec event to trigger after a spec file is executed, automatically posting the test results to Jira's test execution. I am using the Axios library to make the API call to Jira. However, I am encountering an issue where the event does not fire the GET request using the Axios library at all, and it does not throw any error messages.
However, when executing the command using Node, the API successfully invokes and returns response data values. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?
Below is a sample of how the code looks:
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
const func = require('./cypress/support/helper.js');
const axios = require('axios')

async function testAPI() {
  try {
    //Calling get request using axios by providing url and parameters
    const token = "{token}"
    const response = await axios.get('{url/endpoint}', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform',
        'User-Agent': 'xx'
      }
    })
    return response.data;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  failOnStatusCode: true,
  viewportWidth: 1920,
  viewportHeight: 1200,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000, // Time, in milliseconds, to wait until most DOM based commands are considered timed out.
  pageLoadTimeout: 48000, // Time, in milliseconds, to wait for page transition events or cy.visit() commands to fire their page load events. 
  requestTimeout: 20000, // Time, in milliseconds, to wait for a request to go out in a cy.wait() command.
  video: true, // Records a video for each spec file when running tests 
  videoCompression: false, // The quality setting for the video compression, in Constant Rate Factor (CRF) where a lower value results in better quality (at the expense of a higher file size).
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

      // implement node event listeners here
      on('after:spec', (spec, results) => {

        testAPI().then((da) => {
          console.log('Jira verdict posting： ' + da)
        })
      })

      
    }

  },
});

The goal is to invoke an Axios API request that returns response traffic data after the after:spec event is triggered, allowing for the posting of test results into the Jira test case verdict.

The axios call is actually happening, you just can't see it :).
If you make the after:spec callback async and await testAPI(), the console log shows up.
A runnable example:
cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const axios = require('axios')

const highlight = (msg) => `\x1B[41;93;4m${msg}\x1B[m`

async function testAPI() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    console.log(highlight('Response in testAPI function'), response.data, '\n')
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:spec', async () => {
        console.log(highlight('after:spec is running'), '\n')
        const data = await testAPI()  
        console.log(highlight('after axios call： '), data, '\n')
      })
    },
  },
})


Without await testAPI() there is only the log for start of after:spec, because the test runner has stopped before the axios call is completed.


Thank you for sharing your expertise on this; Really appreciate it! A double thumbs up for you! After implementing async/await, it functions as expected.
